# XML parsing: how to return None is element was not found

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I need to parse an XML file, where the same tag might have a different number of children present, such the one shown below:

```
xml_file = '''
<clients>
    <client>
        <name>John</name>
    </client>
    <client>
        <name>Mike</name>
        <age>25</age>
    </client>
</clients>
'''
```

I want the code to return `None` if any tag was not found. My current solution looks like this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

tree = et.fromstring(xml_file)
client_attr = []
for client in tree.iter('client'):
    results = {'name': None, 'age': None}
    name = client.find('name')
    age = client.find('age')

    results.update({
        'name': name.text if name is not None else None,
        'age': age.text if age is not None else None
     }
    )
    client_attr.append(results)
```

However, this seems to be kinda clunky and takes up a lot of space and time when applied to my real data. It seems to me like there should be a way to combine the steps but I could not figure out how.
Thx in advance.

Comment: Do you by this mean that the code ought to return `None` if there are no `client` tags nested within the `clients` tag?

Comment: No, I want the code to return none if the ```client``` tage has not ```age``` tag.

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance, in order to achieve the behaviour which you wish to implement, you have to consider some other problems which will arise, problems which you might have considered already, but alas, you didn't seem to have specified how you planned to proceed with them in the query you posted.

For instance, as you clarified in the comments you want the code, which I assume is part of a function, because if ain't you can't possibly return None or any value in the state in which it was presented in the query; you want it to return None if a tag is found which has no age specified, this raises the question about the rest of the data, meaning, what are you going to do with what you processed thus far, are you going to simply discard it? Then there is the question about how you will inform the user about the discrepancy, and ultimately what's the action you will take to remedy the problem.

This could lead to a more complicated parsing system, but one which is nonetheless more robust, and which attempts to, overall, utilise the resources of the system judiciously.

**Nonetheless**, if this is not what you intended to achieve with your code, then I will simply suggest to:
a) wrap the code into a function, and if do wish to return None when age or name is not found, i.e. when the `find` function returns None, then do so, and the loop won't continue, thus slicing the time overall, except for the worst case scenario when the malformed element is the last one;
b) raise an exception when that occurs, so that the caller deals with it appropriately, which could entail informing the user that the file is not abiding the formatting rules and so on. For this, etree comes with the `ParseError` exception.

Now, a thing to bear in mind is that None is ambiguous since it can stand for anything, and in order for someone to know that in this case it stands for the absence of the age child tag, that will imply that that particular someone is familiar with the code, and/or that the documentation is describing this behaviour, and implicitly that everyone working on the code is reading the said documentation.

In this case due to the manner in which the code is written I would suggest to combat the aforementioned ambiguity with the exception approach, an alternative will be to return an `Optional` type which will either hold `Some` value, in this case a dictionary, or `None`, this will, to some extent enable you to return the data up to the point where it was correct, and None if the first element was already faulty.

**Also,** you don't really require the `update` call for you can just directly assign the values to the dictionary, that might also improve the efficiency of the code a tad.

Answer (score 0):

If pandas can be used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

xml_file = '''
<clients>
    <client>
        <name>John</name>
    </client>
    <client>
        <name>Mike</name>
        <age>25</age>
    </client>
</clients>
'''

df = pd.read_xml(xml_file, xpath = './/client')
print(df.replace(np.nan, None))
```

Without numpy and replace function, pandas will show a NaN.

```
   name   age
0  John  None
1  Mike  25.0
```

Comment: Thx, but not really a viable option since the real xml file has several layers of different depths and I do not need to extract all the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using `beautifulsoup`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_file = """
<clients>
    <client>
        <name>John</name>
    </client>
    <client>
        <name>Mike</name>
        <age>25</age>
    </client>
</clients>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file, "xml")

all_data = []
for client in soup.select("client"):
    all_data.append(
        {
            t.name: t.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
            for t in client.find_all(recursive=False)
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   name  age
0  John  NaN
1  Mike   25
```